# 犬{いぬ}も食{く}わない having a connotation of getting involved in a lover's spat?

Tags: meaning, expressions, anime, connotation

In SAO Progressive (2nd movie), Asuna and Kirito are arguing, and Kirito asks Argo to weigh in. Argo responds "犬｛いぬ｝も食｛く｝わない物｛もの｝に関｛かか｝わる気｛き｝はないよ～", which is officially translated as "Don't pull me into your couple's quarrel." And then Kirito and Asuna, in tandem, react stunned/indignant seemingly at being called a "couple" (asuna says "へーッ？！" [translated as "Huh?"], and kirito says "いぬ？！" [which gets translated as "Couple?"]).

Clip: https://i.imgur.com/sGvYSbf.mp4

[image: Couple's Quarrel image]
[image: Indignant to being called couple]

But here's the thing: the actual phrase doesn't seem to be coded to references couples in particular to me. To also throw a weird wrench into the mix, [jisho.org says](https://jisho.org/search/inumokuwanai) that it simply refers to something that everyone would avoid/dislike, but then goes on to use, as an example, a lover's spat.

So I'm wondering: is a lover's spat something that's strongly coded into/implied by the expression, or can it be used much more widely, and doesn't particularly imply a lover's spat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some monolingual dictionaries (e.g. 三省堂国語辞典　第八版) list 夫婦げんかは犬も食わない as an idiom, and this is where 犬も食わない is used almost exclusively other than about foods.

Comment: Apparently, jisho.org also has that phrase as well ( https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A4%AB%E5%A9%A6%E3%81%92%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AF ). But all that showed up for me was the second part. Thanks!